# How to combine multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
listA = ["A", "B", "C"]

listB = ["1", "2", "3"]

listC = ["!", "@", "#"]
```

If I have these lists, how would I get a new list of

```
[("A", "1", "!"), ("B", "2", "@"), ("!", "@", "#")]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
list(zip(listA,listB,listC))

[('A', '1', '!'), ('B', '2', '@'), ('C', '3', '#')]
```

Comment: That was quick... nice